# Newbie IPhone Removing Soap Envelope

Tags: iphone, xcode, soap

I am looking for a way to remove the envelope around my SOAP Response. The Data is in JSON but doesnt really have levels so if I can remove the envelope I know I can parse it because I put the data into a json file and got the parser working for it. My only problem when I get the response from the server is the envelope surrounding the data.

I have looked alot but cant seem to find a answer. Any help and sample code is appreciated!

This is my soap response

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <AuthenticateUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <AuthenticateUserResult>{"isValid":true,"isContractor":false,"isExpired":false,"isApproved":true,"userID":"e2be94cb-2e74-4eae-91a9-d874735b8647","userType":"DUMP ","trucks":1}</AuthenticateUserResult>
      </AuthenticateUserResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am looking to pull this.

```
{"isValid":true,"isContractor":false,"isExpired":false,"isApproved":true,"userID":"e2be94cb-2e74-4eae-91a9-d874735b8647","userType":"DUMP ","trucks":1}
```

I could be taking a wrong approach but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be overkill for your needs, but here's how I'm doing it.

Get yourself an NSXMLParser. Set its delegate.

In the delegate, look for these methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)characters
```

In the didStartElement method, check if elementName is AuthenticateUserResult. If it is, set a boolean isInAuthenticateUserResult = YES;

In the didEndElement method, set that boolean to no.

In the foundCharacters method, if the boolean is YES then the characters are your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the envelope is just XML have you looked at using [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) to just parse the XML and get the value you want? If you don't like writing stream parsers, you could also check out something like [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML).